# Unable to publish npm package from Github?

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-package

I've published [react-push-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-push-notify) by using this command :

```
   npm login
   npm publish
```

But when I want to publish again through **Github** ( private repository ) by following these steps:

1. Add `publishPackage` to my `package.json`

   ```
       "publishConfig": { "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/" }
   ```
2. Authenticate

   ```
       npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
   ```
3. Publish

   ```
      npm publish
   ```

It invokes this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/react-push-notify
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'react-push-notify@0.2.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

This is my first package on npm and I'm confusing what's difference between publishing to npm and publishing to npm from Github?

Answer (score 0):

**Login & Logout**

```
npm login --scope=@[Organization name] --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm logout --scope=@My-Organization --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

**Publish**

```
npm publish
```